# MXMetricKit: finishExtendedLaunchMeasurement not work

Tags: ios, metrickit

Xcode throw an error when i call the api finishExtendedLaunchMeasurement :

```
[General] Couldn't find persisted ALM/FrontBoard launch signpost id when finishing an ext launch task.


Error Domain=MXErrorDomain Code=5 "Internal failures happened inside of MetricKit." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Internal failures happened inside of MetricKit.}
```

The following code:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // create window

    MXMetricManager.shared.add(self)
    do {
      let task_id = MXLaunchTaskID("1234.zmmm")
      try MXMetricManager.extendLaunchMeasurement(forTaskID: task_id)
      print("some task perform")
      try MXMetricManager.finishExtendedLaunchMeasurement(forTaskID: task_id)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
    return true
  }
```

how i can fix this problem？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not call finishExtendedLaunchMeasurement here
because the app is not launch completely there.
just do it like this, or any other time you want, such as the first screen showed

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (@available(iOS 16.0, *)) {
            [[MetricsManager shared] finishLaunchMeasurement];
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much, I thought this api can break down the startup into finer sub-phases.